# How to reset auto increment in JavaDB

Tags: javadb

I emigrate from MySQL at Java DB to use Embedded Driver for my application
In Java I use this lines of code to reset an auto increment column, like an id.

> String s1 = "DELETE from keeplog where idk = '"+1+"'";
>                         String s2 = "ALTER TABLE keeplog drop idk";
>                         String s3 = "ALTER TABLE keeplog add idk int not null auto_increment primary key";

I search on the Internet and I found this methods:

> String q = "ALTER TABLE init ALTER COLUMN idinit RESTART WITH 1";

and

> String query = "ALTER TABLE pers ALTER idp SET INCREMENT BY 1

I try with both of them but doesn't work.
So, what kind of code I need to put in my Java app to restart a column in Java DB ?

P.S.
I use derby.jar from my jdk1.8.0_25.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem with the second line of code! I didn't pay more attention.. my fault!!!
I know that is a problem for all others who want to reset their auto increment column in Java DB.. so use this line ALTER TABLE table-name ALTER id-name SET INCREMENT BY number

Comment: you can post an answer your own question.